# use android L button in android 4.1 like google plus app

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

i´m looking for a way to use this rounded button from android L in android 4.1 and above like the "new" google plus app. 
 
[image: example for button] 
Is there any backport library or something else (maybe with more android l design features)? 
I have already looked at google.com/design -> ressources and developer.android.com

Comment: your problem is creating round button?

Comment: no my problem is more the "overlay" -> the positioning ^^

Comment: have you tried with margin?

Comment: How can i overlay a button above a layout? If I knew that I could work with margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is just a sample of what you want (I think )

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sockettest.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

you fit left of `imageView` to right of your layout, then set minus margin ( -20 ).

but be careful, `imageView` must be lower than your layout, ( you can swap Layout with `imageView` to see the result)